# Svelte application bug: changing the contents of an array based on the value of a flag fails

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

In a small Svelte app, I have this empty array: `var countries = []`. I want to "fill" this empty array with the members (objects) of a second array if a condition is met, *or* another, if the condition is not met:

```
<script>
    var checkedFlag = true;

    var countries = [];

    var countriesChecked = [
        {code : "AL", name: "Albania"},
        {code : "BE", name : "Belgium"},
        {code : "BG", name : "Bulgaria"},
    ];

    var countriesNotChecked = [{code : "RO", name : "Romania"}];
    
    function toggleChecked(){
        checkedFlag = !checkedFlag;
    }
    
    if (checkedFlag == true) {
        countries = countriesChecked;
    } else {
        countries = countriesNotChecked;
    }
    
    console.log(countries);
    
</script>

<input type="checkbox" on:change={toggleChecked} bind:checked={checkedFlag}> Countries checked: {checkedFlag}
```

I was expecting the console to show:

```
{code : "AL", name: "Albania"},
{code : "BE", name : "Belgium"},
{code : "BG", name : "Bulgaria"}
```

while the checkbox was checked, or

```
{code : "RO", name : "Romania"}
```

while the checkbox was unchecked.

Yet, this doesn't happen, as can be seen in this **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/192f608bcef34c93b2cd8d0a5cc0897c?version=3.23.2)**.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" on:change={toggleChecked} bind:checked={checkedFlag}>
```

You should probably chose between handling the event or binding a variable. They represent the same state transition / event. Having them both makes the data flow much harder to reason about.

Svelte thrives with declarative code, so let's pick the binding (rather than the imperative-style event):

```
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={checkedFlag}>
```

Now we need to make this block reactive:

```js
    if (checkedFlag == true) {
        countries = countriesChecked;
    } else {
        countries = countriesNotChecked;
    }
```

Currently, it runs once when the component is created.

We add a reactive label `$:`:

```js
    $: if (checkedFlag == true) {
        countries = countriesChecked;
    } else {
        countries = countriesNotChecked;
    }
```

Now it will not run when the component is created, but just after, and then it will rerun anytime any of the variable it contains (here: `checkedFlag`, `countries`, or `countriesChecked`) changes.

With that, internal state is fixed, but we still only have one `console.log`. Why? Because we also need to make it reactive:

```js
    $: console.log(countries);
```

This one will rerun anytime `countries` change.

Here.

Reactive blocks describe an async data flow in a declarative and functional-oriented style, much like streaming libraries like RxJS, but with the usual everyday syntax you already know. How cool is that?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I want to be able to operate with the countries array in the view.